# /tree/primary vs /document/primary

Tags: android, documentfile

I am learning how to use SAF. In my demo application, I found out uri path could be ***`/tree/primary`***
and **`/document/primary`**.

I want to know what is the difference?

Comment: One is for a tree (folder) the other for a file. Please confirm.

Comment: Thank you! I got it